# Return data to Android from Firebase Function

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**What I am trying to do:** Simply return data from Firebase Cloud Function.

The function is used to create a payment order in the payment gateway's server.

My required data about the order's details are present in the `function(err,data)` (see below), but I need this data sent back to my Android app.

**Problem I faced:** I could see the data printed in the Firebase console's log but it doesn't return to my Android app.

**My Firebase Cloud Function:**

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.order = functions.https.onCall((amnt, response) => {
  const Ippopay = require('node-ippopay');

  const ippopay_instance = new Ippopay({
    public_key: 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY',
    secret_key: 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
  });
    
  ippopay_instance.createOrder({
    amount: amnt, 
    currency: 'DOLLAR',
    payment_modes: "cc,dc,nb,cheque",
    customer: {
      name: "Test",
      email: "test@gmail.com",
      phone: {
        country_code: "42",
        national_number: "4376543210"
      }
    }
  }, function (err, data) {
    return data.order.order_id;
  });
});
```

**My Android client-side code:**

```java
public class Payment extends AppCompatActivity implements IppoPayListener {
    Button pay;
    EditText amount;
    private FirebaseFunctions mFunctions;

    TextView order_data;
    String data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pay=findViewById(R.id.pay_button);
        amount=findViewById(R.id.user_amount);
        order_data=findViewById(R.id.data_text);
        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("PAY Button clicked", "yes");
                mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance("us-central1");
               
                mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("order").call(5).continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        HttpsCallableResult result=task.getResult();
                        if(result !=null)
                        {
                            data=result.getData().toString();
                            return result.getData().toString();

                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                });
                order_data.setText(data);
                onPaymentClick();
            }
        });
    }
    
    /* ... */
}
```

I'm a Beginner so there's a high possibility of some dead silly mistakes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what your code looks like at the moment, you have a mix of code from a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and the older [HTTP Request Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

To return data from a callable Cloud Function, you should return a [`Promise`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises), a method of running asynchronous code that returns a value. Older JavaScript and many other languages use callbacks instead, which is what you have here.

In it's simplest form, this callback-based method:

```
someModule.doSomething(input, function (err, result) {
  // check for errors and handle result
});
```

would be converted to use Promises using:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  someModule.doSomething(
    input,
    (err, result) => err ? reject(err) : resolve(result) // short form of "if error, reject with an error, otherwise resolve (succeed) with result"
  )
});
```

For errors to be handled correctly by clients, you need to [wrap any errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) in a [`functions.https.HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.httpserror).

Combining this together gives:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.order = functions.https.onCall((amnt, context) => {
  const Ippopay = require('node-ippopay');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const ippopay_instance = new Ippopay({
      public_key: 'YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY',
      secret_key: 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
    });
    
    ippopay_instance.createOrder({
      amount: amnt, 
      currency: 'DOLLAR',
      payment_modes: "cc,dc,nb,cheque",
      customer: {
        name: "Test",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
        phone: {
          country_code: "42",
          national_number: "4376543210"
        }
      }
    }, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        // something went wrong, send error back to caller
        reject(new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Ippopay threw an unexpected error', err));
        return;
      }
     
      // successful, send data back to caller
      resolve(data.order.order_id);
    }); 
  });
});
```

You should also make sure you make use of [`context.auth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext#auth) to restrict access to this function. You wouldn't want to bill the wrong customer.