# Return data from firebase functions back to android

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**What am Trying to do :** Simply Return data from firebase cloud function.

The function is used to create a payment order in the payment gateway's server.

My required data about the order's details are present in the function(err,data)(*Refer code*) I need this data sent back to my android app.

**Problem I faced :** I could see the data printed in the firebase console's log but it doesn't return to my android app back.

**My firebase cloud function :**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
exports.order = functions.https.onCall((amnt, response) => {

    const Ippopay = require('node-ippopay');

    var ippopay_instance = new Ippopay({
        public_key: 'pk_live_0WZhCNC5l7PJ',
        secret_key: 'sk_live_GXc8SLdxkBp',
      });
      
      ippopay_instance.createOrder({
        amount: amnt, 
        currency: 'DOLLAR',
        payment_modes: "cc,dc,nb,cheque",
        customer: {
            name: "Test",
            email: "test@gmail.com",
            phone: {
                country_code: "42",
                national_number: "4376543210"
            }
        }
    }, function  (err, data){
       
       return data.order.order_id;
    }); 
});
```

**My android client side code :**

```
public class Payment extends AppCompatActivity implements IppoPayListener {

    Button pay;
    EditText amount;
    private FirebaseFunctions mFunctions;

    TextView order_data;
    String data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pay=findViewById(R.id.pay_button);
        amount=findViewById(R.id.user_amount);
        order_data=findViewById(R.id.data_text);
        pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("PAY Button clicked", "yes");
                mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance("us-central1");
               
                mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("order").call(5).continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        HttpsCallableResult result=task.getResult();
                        if(result !=null)
                        {
                            data=result.getData().toString();
                            return result.getData().toString();

                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                 });
                order_data.setText(data);
                onPaymentClick();

            }
        });
    }
```

I'm a Beginner so there's a high possibility of some dead silly mistakes. :)

Comment: Please avoid to answer twice the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66793912/firebase-function-return-data-to-android

Answer (score 0):

In your cloud function, you can’t just return a value, you need to send it as a response using `response.json()`. Change this line

```js
return data.order.order_id;
```

to this

```js
response.json({ orderId: data.order.order_id });
```

See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#add-the-addmessage-function) for an example.

Comment: Like the OP, you are mixing up [Callable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) and [HTTP Request](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) cloud functions. While using `response.json` works for a HTTP request function, this is a callable function, where the data returned is the result of the returned `Promise`. Take a look at [my answer on the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66796577/3068190).